# Expected ETA to avail Pipeline I/O and runtime parameters in apache beam GCP dataflow pipeline using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Just wanted to know do we have more pipeline I/O and runtime parameters available with new version (3.X) of python. If I am correct then currently apache beam provide only File-based IOs: textio, avroio, tfrecordio when using python. But with Java we have more options available like File-based IOs, BigQueryIO, BigtableIO, PubSubIO and SpannerIO.

In my requirement I want to use BigQueryIO in GCP dataflow pipeline using python 3.X, But currently it is not available. Does anyone have some update on ETA when will it be available by apache beam.

Answer (score 3):

The BigTable Connector for Python 3 is under development for some time now. Currently, there is no ETA but you can follow the relevant [Pull-Request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8457) from the official Apache Beam repository for further updates.

Comment: There was a typo mistake in my question, I just corrected it. In my requirement I am looking for BigQueryIO connector for python 3.

Answer (score 0):

[BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) has been available for quite some time in the Apache Beam Python SDK.

There is also a [Pub/Sub IO available](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py) as well as [BigTable (write)](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py). [SpannerIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10712) is being worked on as we speak.

This page has more detail https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/

**UPDATE:**

In line with OP giving more details, it turns out that indeed using value providers in the BigQuery query string was not supported.

This has been remedied in the following PR: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/11040 and will most likely be part of the 2.21.0 release.

**UPDATE 2:**
This new feature has been added in the 2.20.0 release of Apache Beam
https://beam.apache.org/blog/2020/04/15/beam-2.20.0.html

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: I am talking about pipeline I/O for BigQuery which can use runtime parameters while executing pipeline stages. In other words If I want to use dynamic query in "beam.io.BigQuerySource" then currently it is not available with python 3.x

Here is the google cloud standard doc: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options 

on this page you can check for "Pipeline I/O and runtime parameters"

Comment: I see. Yes then you are correct that the usage of ValueProvider's for the BigQuery query does not seem to be supported. But looking at the source code, it should be a relatively easy fix. I'll investigate a bit more and see if I can put together a PR.

Comment: Perfect, please keep me posted once you get any progressive update on PR.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9305.

Comment: Did we hear anything on raised PR?

Comment: Unfinished PR is at: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/11040 Expecting the feature to most likely be part of the 2.21.0 release.

Comment: @KaustubhGhole the PR has been merged and will most likely be part of the 2.21.0 release. In the meantime, you can add the changes in the PR to your local installation of Beam and run Dataflow with the custom SDK flag using this modified package, if you want to.

Comment: Yes I will try to add the changes covered in the PR. Also When are they releasing version 2.21.0. ?

Comment: 2.21.0 should still be at least 2 months away probably. It is possible they will add this fix to 2.20.0 though which should be out very soon.

Comment: The fix was added to 2.20.0 which released on Friday last week: https://beam.apache.org/blog/2020/04/15/beam-2.20.0.html

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: I will start using new released version and see If I get success. Thanks !